# Maxmind geoip, don't find ip

Tags: php, geoip, maxmind, geolitecity

I have a php docker container that i use on my local environement.

In the dockerfile i put this

```
RUN apt-get install -y \
    geoip-bin \
    geoip-database \
    libgeoip-dev
RUN pecl install geoip-1.1.1
RUN docker-php-ext-enable geoip
RUN echo "geoip.custom_directory=\"/usr/share/GeoIP/\"" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-geoip.ini
RUN wget "https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-City&license_key=TOTOTOT&suffix=tar.gz" -O /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.tar.gz && gunzip --force /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.tar.gz && ln -s /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat
```

Unfortunatelly sometimes when i try to access some ip adresses i get the follwing error "Could not find ip in database".

So my question is the following. I saw that when you provide an ip like this 88.168.67.43 it doesn't find the information about it. because in the maxmind file we have something with /24 that is needed which is the CIDR.

Maxmind provide a program that convert file in CIDR format to classic csv. But i get a mmdb file and not a csv file.... any idea on how to get the file with the right ip adress ?

Or if i could easily change my ip from 88.168.67.43 to CIDR notation ?